# Blazor application, NU1201 and .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.2. Our Blazor Server application’s solution comprises of several projects and all of them are targeted to .NET Core 3.1

When I am trying to publish my application from Visual Studio, I get the below error:

NU1201 Project GCB.Storage is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) / win-x64. Project GCB.Storage supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)

Visual Studio says I get above error for project "GCB.Main" in GCB.Main.csproj. GCB.Main has a reference to the project GCB.Storage. Both of these projects’ target framework is set to .NET Core 3.1. I double checked all the dependencies and project references in both the projects and none of them depend on .NET Core 3.0

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1201) says that error might occur when "A dependency project doesn't contain a framework compatible with the current project. Typically, the project's target framework is a higher version than the consuming project."

Here are my publishing profile parameters in Visual Studio:

- Configuration: Debug
- Target framework: netcoreapp3.1
- Deployment mode: Framework-Dependent
- Target runtime: win-x64

I looked at control panel on the server where I am publishing and it has "Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 (x64) from Visual Studio" update installed. Do I need to configure/install anything on the server? I do not see an entry for .NET Core Runtime 3.1 but I do see entries for MSFT .NET Core - 3.0.0 (x86), one for x64, and one for MSFT .NET Core 3.0.0 - Windows Server Hosting. Should I install .NET Core 3.1 runtime explicitly even though I installed Visual Studio 2019 16.5.2 on the same server?

Please note that I am able to compile/rebuild the solution without any errors on the same server where I am publishing it to. However when I try to publish I get above publishing errors.

Below is my pubxml

--

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>a2939d6d-c286-40c3-a015-e946d67cd806</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <publishUrl>C:\GCB</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

--

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried doing `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` from the cmdline to see if the issue is with the framework or with VS?

Comment: I went ahead and installed MSFT .NET Core 3.1.3 Windows Server Hosting and tried publishing from Visual Studio but no luck. I will now try using dotnet build and publish commands and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @ESG dotnet build and publish commands worked! Files were published at \bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1 If I want to publish the application to a specific location, is it just a matter of copying these files from netcoreapp3.1 folder? why do you think visual studio's publish profile is not working?

Comment: You can copy those file, or you can specify `-o <directory>` when publishing. As for why the VS profile isn't working, it's hard to tell without looking at the profile. Can you show your `pubxml` profile?

Comment: @ESG I updated my original post with pubxml. Interestingly targetframework still shows netcoreapp3.0 whereas in the interface from visual studio i see that target framework is set to 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the publishing profile is out of sync with the UX for whatever reason.

Update your pubxml file to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` and it should publish without issues

Comment: thanks! do you think i need ".net core 3.1 windows server hosting" even though i see "Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 (x64) from Visual Studio" installed?

Comment: Those are different things. Server hosting is to host the application within IIS, and not needed to build or publish: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1